# How to use escape sequences in strings that work with both TMemo and TIdLogFile

Tags: string, c++builder, indy, vcl

Using C++Builder XE6, I wrote a log file class that derives from TIdLogFile:

```
#include <IdLogFile.hpp>

class TIdLogFileEx : public TIdLogFile
{
    typedef TIdLogFile inherited;

    public:
        inline __fastcall TIdLogFileEx (TComponent* AOwner) : inherited(AOwner) {}
        inline __fastcall TIdLogFileEx () : inherited() {}

        virtual void __fastcall LogInfo (const System::UnicodeString AText);
};

void __fastcall TIdLogFileEx::LogInfo (const System::UnicodeString AText)
{
    LogWriteString(_D("Info : ") + AText + EOL);
}
```

This works as expected for plaintext strings, but not for strings that contain escape sequences.

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click (TObject *Sender)
{
    UnicodeString U = "\x95" + UnicodeString("Test") + "\x85";
    AnsiString A = U;

    TIdLogFileEx* File = new TIdLogFileEx;

    try
    {
        File->Filename = "Test.log";
        File->Active   = true;

        File->LogInfo(U);
        File->LogInfo(A);
        Memo1->Lines->Add(U);
        Memo1->Lines->Add(A);

        U = _D("\x95") + UnicodeString("Test") + _D("\x85");
        A = U;

        File->LogInfo(U);
        File->LogInfo(A);
        Memo1->Lines->Add(U);
        Memo1->Lines->Add(A);
    }
    __finally
    {
        delete File;
    }
}
```

The output to Memo1 is:

```
•Test…
•Test…
Test        (actually <U+0095>Test<U+0085>)
?Test?
```

The log file contains:

```
Info : ?Test?
Info : ?Test?
Info : •Test…
Info : ?Test?
```

How do I use escape sequences that work with both `TMemo` and `TIdLogFile` / `TIdLogFileEx`, and are also portable?

Note that `_D("\x2022")` and `_D("\x2026")` don't work as expected when the default string type is `AnsiString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my `TIdLogFileEx` class to write to the log file in UTF-8 encoding.

Here's the code:

```
#include <IdLogFile.hpp>

class TIdLogFileEx : public TIdLogFile
{
    typedef TIdLogFile inherited;

    protected:    
        virtual void __fastcall LogWriteString (const System::UnicodeString AText);

    public:
        inline __fastcall TIdLogFileEx (TComponent* AOwner) : inherited(AOwner) {}
        inline __fastcall TIdLogFileEx () : inherited() {}

        virtual void __fastcall LogInfo (const System::UnicodeString AText);
};

void __fastcall TIdLogFileEx::LogInfo (const System::UnicodeString AText)
{
    LogWriteString(_D("Info : ") + AText + EOL);
}

void __fastcall TIdLogFileEx::LogWriteString (const System::UnicodeString AText)
{
    if (FFileStream)
    {
        _di_IIdTextEncoding Encoding = IndyTextEncoding_UTF8();

        WriteStringToStream(FFileStream, AText, Encoding);
    }
}
```

This solved the problem for my specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with escape sequences themselves, but with the specific values that they represent.

You are converting ANSI characters to Unicode characters and back to ANSI, where those conversions are based on the OS's default ANSI locale (represented by the RTL's global [`DefaultSystemCodePage`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DefaultSystemCodePage) variable).  For instance, in Windows-1252, ANSI bytes `0x95` and `0x85` map to Unicode codepoints `U+2022` (`•`) and `U+2026` (`…`), respectively. Which is what you are seeing.

In general, ANSI<->Unicode conversions are **potentially lossy** for characters outside of the ASCII range (`0x00-0x7F`).

So, in the 1st case:

- you are starting with ANSI characters `0x95`/`0x85` appended to a `UnicodeString`, invoking ANSI->Unicode conversions
- then you assign the resulting `UnicodeString` to an `AnsiString`, invoking a Unicode->ANSI conversion
- then you assign that `AnsiString` back to a `UnicodeString`, invoking an ANSI->Unicode conversion

You *happen* to have **lossless** conversions in this case, only because the ANSI characters in question *happen* to be supported by your system's locale.

But, in the 2nd case:

- you are starting with Unicode characters `U+0095`/`U+0085` appended to a `UnicodeString`, so no conversions are invoked
- then you assign the resulting `UnicodeString` to an `AnsiString`, invoking a Unicode->ANSI conversion
- then you assign that `AnsiString` back to a `UnicodeString`, invoking an ANSI->Unicode conversion

You end up with **data loss** on the assignment to `AnsiString`, since there are no ANSI characters in your system's locale that map to those particular Unicode characters, thus those characters are getting converted to ANSI `0x3F` (`?`), which then converts back to Unicode as `U+003F` (`?`).

You are using a Unicode version of Delphi, so the `TMemo` is simply displaying the final `UnicodeString` as-is, since it internally uses a Unicode-based `HWND`.

On the other hand, `TIdLogFile` internally converts Unicode characters to Indy's native 8-bit binary encoding <sup>1</sup> (because the `TIdLog...` components can be connected to TCP components which can transmit binary data).  And under the 8-bit encoding, Unicode characters are simply truncated as-is into 8-bit bytes, where Unicode characters greater than `U+00FF` are converted to byte `0x3F` (`?`). This is hard-coded behavior, you can't change it without modifying Indy's source code.

<sup>1</sup>: In ANSI-based compilers, `TIdLogFile` converts `AnsiString` inputs to Unicode using the system locale before then converting to 8-bit.

In the case where you are using Unicode characters `U+0095`/`U+0085`, they get written as-is as truncated bytes `0x95`/`0x85`. You then see `•`/`…` in the file if you *view* it as Windows-1252 (or other similar locale).

If you need to log Unicode strings to a file with locale support, `TIdLogFile` is not the correct solution.  Use a different solution, such as the RTL's own `TStreamWriter` class, which supports `Sysutils::TEncoding`.

And, if you need portable logic, don't rely on **lossy** ANSI<->Unicode conversions.  Use **loss-less** conversions, either using ANSI locales that support ALL of the Unicode characters you need, or else using UTF encodings instead, such as UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Remy. I use `TIdLogFile`, because I'm logging data sent/received by `TIdHTTP`. I need to log (debug) info related to the HTTP content to the same log file. I know about ANSI <-> Unicode conversion. I use UnicodeString, not AnsiString, and was looking for a way to generate message strings containing bullets or ellipses, that can both be logged and displayed, without doing some sort of conversion in-between. I probably need to change `TIdLogFileEx` to avoid the 8-bit binary encoding, right?

Comment: Am I wrong to think that bullets and ellipses are available in (almost) every codepage, since they are common typographical symbols?

Comment: @MartinNijhoff "*I'm logging data sent/received by `TIdHTTP`*" - you can't use *unencoded* Unicode characters in HTTP headers, but an HTTP body could contain raw or encoded Unicode characters (where the `Content-Type` header, or even the body itself, usually explains which encoding is used). If you are logging extra stuff in the same log file, it is really not a good idea to use a different charset to create a mixed-encoding text file. "*generate message strings containing bullets or ellipses*" - I would just use ASCII hypens (`-`) and periods (`...`) instead of Unicode bullets and ellipses.

Comment: @MartinNijhoff "*bullets and ellipses are available in (almost) every codepage*"" - not as common as you think. Not to mention, there are over a dozen different kinds of bullets, and a half-dozen ellipses. Even if they were common, they would use different byte values in different charsets.